# position the polygon by dragging the mouse

Tags: materials, 3d-view

is it possible to position the circle , created by procedural maps , by dragging the mouse over the object in the viewport?

could be by addon.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not Exacly. But you can use empty.

Like This:

- just reset in Mapping Node Position
- create new Empty and drag to surface of your Cube
- Add in Texture Cordinate Object - "Empty"

And should looks like that:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help
but there is a problem :

when I send the empty to the top of the cube the circle disappears

Comment: @Beegs works just fine for me, no idea what could be wrong on your end :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun way: create a setup like this:

[image]

Now add 3 drivers to *Combine XYZ* node:

[image] [image] [image]

The simplest way to do that is to right-click *X Location* in the *Numbers Panel* in 3D viewport, *"Copy as a New Driver"*, right-click on the *X* field in *Combine XYZ* node, *Paste Driver*, right-click, *Edit Driver*, change to *Scripted Expression*, change sign, repeat for the two other drivers.

Now you can search for a sphere, and once you're done, you can duplicate the *Combine XYZ* node:

[image]

Move the cube back to XYZ=0,0,0, and use your saved (duplicated) *Combine XYZ* nodes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: actually I wanted something like this:
https://blendermarket.com/products/mapping-gesture

I've tried it but it's not good with procedural maps.

do you know anything about this?